# TypeORM Migration: File must contain a TypeScript / JavaScript code and export a DataSource instance

Tags: migration, typeorm

When trying to autogenerate migrations I get the following error.

File must contain a TypeScript / JavaScript code and export a DataSource instance

This is the command that I am running:

```js
typeorm migration:generate projects/core/migrations/user -d db_config.ts -o
```

And my db_config.ts file looks like this:

```js
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "postgres",
  host: process.env.PGHOST,
  port: 5432,
  username: process.env.PGUSER,
  password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
  database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
  entities: ["./projects/**/entities/*.ts"],
  migrations: ["./projects/**/migrations/**.js"],
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false,
}); 

export default AppDataSource
```

My current file structure looks like this:

- back_end
  -- projects
  --- index.ts
  --- db_config.ts

And my index.ts file looks like this:

```js
import express from "express";
import { AppDataSource } from "./data-source";
import budget_app from "./projects/budget_app/routes";

export const app = express();
const port = 3000;

AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Data Source has been initialized!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error during Data Source initialization", err);
  });

// export default AppDataSource;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!!!!");
});

app.use("/budget_app", budget_app);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I am also running this in a docker container along with my postgres database. I have confirmed that the connection works because if I do synchronize=true it will create the table just fine. I just can't create the migration.

So I'm confused and don't know where to go from here to fix the issue. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 15):

I had trouble with `migrations` in `typeorm`, and finally found a solution that will work consistently.

For me, build and then using `js datasource` didn't work, So i provide my solution for those who steel have struggle with `typeorm-migrations`.

Here is my step by step solution:

1. Create your `datasource` config in a file like `datasource.config.ts`.

   ```ts
   import * as mysqlDriver from 'mysql2';
   import {DataSourceOptions} from 'typeorm';
   import dotenv from 'dotenv';

   dotenv.config();

   export function getConfig() {
       return {
           driver: mysqlDriver,
           type: 'mysql',
           host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
           port: parseInt(process.env.MYSQL_PORT, 10),
           username: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
           password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
           database: process.env.MYSQL_DB,
           synchronize: false,
           migrations: [__dirname + '/../../typeorm-migrations/*.{ts,js}'],
           entities: [__dirname + '/../**/entity/*.{ts,js}'],
       } as DataSourceOptions;
   }
   ```
2. Create a file with a name like `migration.config.ts`.

   ```ts
   const datasource = new DataSource(getConfig()); // config is one that is defined in datasource.config.ts file
   datasource.initialize();
   export default datasource;
   ```
3. Now you can define your migration commands in the `package.json` file.

   ```json
   "migration:up": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --project ./tsconfig.json ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:run -d config/migration.config.ts",
   "migration:down": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --project ./tsconfig.json ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:revert -d config/migration.config.ts"
   ```

With running `yarn run migration:up` you will be able to run your defined migrations in `typeorm-migrations` folder.

Comment: No need for ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node, you can just type ts-node. It will automatically look up in node_modules, because the command is inside package.json

Comment: I get an error:  "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: please check your pathnames in `migrations` and `entities` attributes

Comment: The `datasource.initialize()` call returns a promise, but you ignored this. It could cause a problem.

Comment: @AlexShepel, yes, it returns some promise, but it's bounded to main thread, so after termination of main thread, it will be dropped.
I will be glad to hear if you have further concern.

Comment: I was able to run up command. However, down command is giving
`TypeORMError: No migration CoffeeRefactor1711558060023 was found in the source code. Make sure you have this migration in your codebase and its included in the connection options.` Moreover, my migration file has a different number at the end, not the one shown in error

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when using a `.env` file (if you don't have a .env file, this answer probably is irrelevant for you).

It seems, that the CLI does not pick environment variables from dotenv, so you have to load them yourself. E.g., using `dotenv` library, put this on top of your data-source file:

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

// export const AppDataSource = new DataSource()...
```

Alternatively, provide real environment variables when running the script:

`PGHOST=... PGUSER=... PGDATABASE=... PGPASSWORD=... typeorm migration:generate ...`

Answer (score 5):

I was running into the same issues (typeorm 0.3.4). I was just using `npx typeorm migration:show -d ./src/data-source.ts` and getting the same error as above (`File must contain a TypeScript / JavaScript code and export a DataSource instance`), while generating the migration file itself worked somehow, but not running/showing the migrations themselves.
My datasource looks like this

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['dist/entities/*.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/migrations/*.js'],
});
```

because my `tsc` output lives in `/dist.` So based on the comments above I started using the datasource file that was generated from TypeScript and the error message changed:

```
npx typeorm migration:run -d ./dist/appDataSource.js
CannotExecuteNotConnectedError: Cannot execute operation on "default" connection because connection is not yet established.
```

So I looked into the database logs and realized it wanted to connect to postgres with the standard unix user, it wasn't honoring the connection strings in the datasource code. I had to supply all environment variables to the command as well and it worked:
`DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/tsgraphqlserver npx typeorm migration:run -d ./dist/appDataSource.js`

Answer (score 3):

I am actually running into the same issue.

I was able to resolve it by using `*.js` instead of `*.ts`

Please try something like this:

`tsc && typeorm migration:generate -d db_config.ts projects/core/migrations/user`

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "esnext",
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "outDir": "./build",
      "removeComments": false,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
    }
  }
```

I recommend you open an issue on the typeorm github repo, I think it might be a bug.

Comment: what version of typeorm are you using?
i tried with 0.3.4 and I got the same error

Comment: Facing the same problem - I tried this solution and I think it fixed it for me (can't say for sure as I am getting a new error now xD but I think unrelated) Edit: I'm on v0.3.4

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to `package.json` scripts section:

```
      "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
      "migration:run": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run -d ./src/data-source.ts",
      "schema:sync": "npm run typeorm schema:sync -- -d src/data-source.ts",
      "migration:show": "npm run typeorm migration:show -- -d src/data-source.ts",
      "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -d src/data-source.ts",
      "migration:create": "npm run typeorm migration:create"
```

You can then use `npm run migration:create -- src/migration` for example

Answer (score 1):

I was receveing this problem when i runing `npx typeorm migration:generate`

> Error during migration generation: Error: Given data source file must
> contain export of a DataSource instance

For who are **creating datasource** instance **using javascript**
My suggestion is to export an object which contains the `dataSource` property

```
const { DataSource } = require('typeorm');

const dataSource = new DataSource({
  // Yours configs
});

dataSource.initialize();

module.exports = { dataSource };
```

And now i hope that this problem fix

Answer (score 1):

### For TypeScript

I found it better to build your project and work with the `npx typeorm` cli, instead of using the `typeorm-ts-node-esm` or the `typeorm-ts-node-commonjs`. Because in TypeScript, we usually have crazy configurations and build phases in our tsconfigs and the build pipeline in general.

So it's better to build your project first, then follow me in the next following steps:

### For vanilla JavaScript users, *or after building TypeScript*

errors that you should investigate first before are the following:

1. If you're using environment variables, make sure they're getting read **again**.
2. If you're using `import/export` or `require`, it DOES NOT matter, it's the same, safe some headache.
3. It's better to have a separate file only for defining your `DataSource`, to avoid mistakes and other potential bugs.

### Example:

please note, you don't have to follow my Datasource config, this is just an example.

#### In vanilla JavaScript or in TypeScript:

```js
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { MyModel } from "./models/index.js";

const variables = dotenv.config(); // <<<<<  load the environment variables again! (if you have any)

export default new DataSource({
  type: "mysql",
  host: variables.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: variables.DATABASE_PORT,
  username: variables.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: variables.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: variables.DATABASE_NAME,
  entities: [MyModel], // or you can do it by file path string, ex: // ./dist/models/*.js
  synchronize: false,
  logging: false,
  subscribers: [],
  migrations: []
});
```

Now, run any typeorm cli command on the JavaScript file (`.js`), not on TypeScript files (`.ts`), for example:

Notice that I'm specifying that the Datasource from ./dist (it must be in `.js` not in `.ts`):

```bash
$ environment=development npx typeorm migration:generate ./src/migrations -d ./dist/server/DataSource.js
```

Things to keep in mind:

- you can't export the dataSource more than once in the file, for example, you can't have both `export default` and `export const`.
- Make sure you're creating a new instance, so, make sure you're calling `new DataSource`, you have to return a `DataSource` instance, not only an object.
- Make sure the file paths you're specifying to the cli are correct and are in the arguments are in the correct order.
- I'm not sure if this is only the case if you're using typeScript, but the output file from the above command will be in a `.ts` extension, if you want it to be in JavaScript, add the `-o` option

It works.